# I want to use SQLIGHT how can I set a db file into my project using eclipse android

Tags: android

i want to build a db file where i can

1.withdraw relevant info from tables I already inserted there
2.add to this db file new values

but the main thing I want db file with info already stored in the application where 1,2 are optional from it can someone please help me ? it will mean a lot thanks :)...

Comment: This is a duplicate, refer to this question for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Google does a great example of this in their Notepad tutorial found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)